# Get the 10 most similar rows according to another row

Tags: mysql

How can I get rows according to another rows data. E.g. I want to get advertisements according to other.

I know how the comparison is made, and I know how to get the score of the currently active advertisements, but I don't know how to get the advertisements.

My current query is as follows - BUT it will return 10 x the same row, and NOT the ten most similar advertisements.

```
SELECT
    a.AdvertisementID as A_AdvertisementID,
    IF(a.Topic LIKE a2.Topic, 50, 0) + IF(a.Description LIKE a2.Description, 40, 0) + IF(a.Cate_CategoryID LIKE a2.Cate_CategoryID, 10, 0) as A_Score,
    a.AdvertisementID as A_AdvertisementID,
    a.Topic as A_Topic,
    LEFT(a.Description, 300) as A_Description,
    a.Price as A_Price,
    a.Type as A_Type
FROM
    ".DB_PREFIX."A_Advertisements a2,
    ".DB_PREFIX."A_Advertisements a
WHERE
    a2.AdvertisementID <> a.AdvertisementID
AND
    a.AdvertisementID = :a_id
ORDER BY
    A_Score DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [MySQL Fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) capabilities. It allows to search for *similar* textual contents in the database instead of searching for appropriate substrings (like the `LIKE` does). You won't need to calculate the "score" of similarity by hand then.

There are plenty of examples in the web.

If you always want to retrieve at least *X* news (provided that *X* news exists) even if there are no similar ones, try this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(Title, Description, Content) AGAINST("News title") AS score
ORDER BY score DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0, 10
```

I assume that *X* is 10 and the *News title* is the title of the news that the related ones is being looked for and that the fulltext index is on `Title`, `Description` and `Content` columns.

Comment: Well, I want to get the MOST similar records, but if there are no similar records I want 10 random. Is that also achievable with FULLTEXT-search? :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only select columns from `a`, and in your WHERE you said that `a.AdvertisementID = :a_id`. Select the columns from `a2` and you should get different results.

```
SELECT
    a2.AdvertisementID as A_AdvertisementID,
    IF(a.Topic LIKE a2.Topic, 50, 0) + IF(a.Description LIKE a2.Description, 40, 0) +     IF(a.Cate_CategoryID LIKE a2.Cate_CategoryID, 10, 0) as A_Score,
    a2.Topic as A_Topic,
    LEFT(a2.Description, 300) as A_Description,
    a2.Price as A_Price,
    a2.Type as A_Type
```